# Comprehensive list of TLD subdomains?

Tags: dns, tld

I'm having a hard time finding a comprehensive list of ALL TLD subdomains. The information is scattered about the separate registries and there doesn't appear to be one complete list.

```
examples

ca.us
md.us
pr.us
mil.ar
lg.jp
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a list maintained by mozilla at http://publicsuffix.org/